# Can't rewrite observable variable in mobx store

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, mobx, mobx-react

Here is my Mobx store:

```js
import { observable } from 'mobx';
import fb from '../Firebase';
import User from '../User';

export default class Profile {

  @observable profile = {};
  @observable uid = null;

  /**
   * @return {void}
   */
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
    fb.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
      this.uid = user.currentUser.uid;
      fb.profiles.child(this.uid).on('value', (snapshot) => {

        // Doesn't matter what I will do here with this.profile...
        this.profile = snapshot.val();
        
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Trying to use the profile observable property from the observer. But for some reason I can't get the updated status from it.

If I update the profile before the "fb.profiles.child" so not from the callback, than it will be works.

Anyone has an idea why is it happening? I think maybe because its already mounted to the observer or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

In order to get object properly updated, you should use `observable` (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observable.html) and `Object.assign` for defining the `profile`.

Here are few (untested) examples:

```
@observable profile = observable({});
.
.
.
this.profile = Object.assign({}, this.profile, snapshot.val());
```

If `Object.assign` doesn't trigger the update, then you need to use `extendObservable()` (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html):

```
@observable profile = observable({});
.
.
.
extendObservable(profile, snapshot.val());
```

Another alternative is to use `observable.map` (https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) for more complex structures:

```
@observable profile = observable.map({ profileData: {} });
.
.
.
const currentProfile = this.profile.get('profileData'); 
this.profile.set('profileData', Object.assign({}, currentProfile, snapshot.val()));
```

Comment: Still no luck with it. If I print the profile to the console from store with a simple method what I call from the component, than the profile date will be the updated data in the console, but empty object in the component.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

So solve my issue with the question is not possible, the most important part is missing.

There was a componentWillMount in the component. After deleted it solved my issue.